# 2.92, Simple Boolean, Won't Work... Why?

Tags: modifiers

I am no stranger to booles, but this one won't work and it is driving me crazy. What am I missing here?

[Project file here.](https://www.dropbox.com/s/9rxbrguipkizdxv/why-wont-this-boole.blend?dl=0)

[image]

Comment: Invert Normals Shift+N of "Channel" object, they are pointed inside (you can see red faces from outside if "Face Orientation" overlay is enabled ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.) select channel

[image]

2.) Tab -> change to edit mode

3.) A -> select all

4.) mesh -> normals -> recalculate outside

[image]

5.) select all vertices at the end of your channel and press 'f' to create a closing face (make sure you are in "vertex select" mode

[image]
[image]

6.) tab -> object mode

7.) change to "display as" -> bounds

8.) result

[image]

Comment: Those damn normals always get me!  Thanks so much Chris, this is exactly what I'm after. Learned a lot just now.

Comment: no problem. I made all mistakes a dozen times.... :D